# What is the grammar behind "insisted he >do<"?

Tags: passive-voice, subjunctives, mandative

> Unfortunately, he forgot to support the brickwork above the hole he had made, and the bedroom floor above sagged about a meter and they had to call in a builder to put it right. *It was his wife who insisted he **do** any work **out** in the garden in future*.

The last sentence I am not sure if it is right, after "It was his wife who insisted he DO..." Maybe it is not right. Why *do*? —maybe *him doing* instead of the written example? Please explain the grammar.

Comment: Where is the fragment from?  Did you write it yourself?  "Who insisted [that] **he ...whatever**" - the bold part is a subordinate clause, in which 'he' is the subject 'do' is the predicate.  Perhaps you want to make them correspond in person and number?

Comment: No, friend, it was written by russian teachers, actually i understand what the matter is,  but, it sounds not pretty to my mind

Answer (score 1):

### Correct

Any of the following are correct:

- It was his wife who insisted he do any work out in the garden in ***the*** future.
- His wife insisted he do any work out in the garden in ***the*** future.
- His wife insisted he do all work out in the garden in ***the*** future.
- His wife insisted he do all future work out in the garden.
- His wife insisted he do all future work in the garden. *(Recommended)*
- His wife insisted he work exclusively in the garden in the future. *(Recommended)*

I recommend either of the last two sentences because, as a general rule, "shorter is better."

### Incorrect

I believe (with about 80% certainty) the following is incorrect.

- It was his wife who insisted on him doing any work out in the garden in the future.

The problem there is with the word **him**. I believe it should be **he** because **he** is the subject of that clause.

#### Explanation

There are many permutations and combinations available that are also correct that I did not list. I'm sorry I can't explain the technicalities of why these are correct as I am a native English speaker and most native speakers often don't know **why** what is correct is so, only **what** is correct and what is not.

Comment: In the "incorrect" case, pedants would insist on "his," indicating the the verb is a gerund, and thus a possessive is in order. However, common usage accepts both "him" and "his." I do not think that "he" would be correct here. Not that your reasoning is wrong--"he" has just as much of an argument as the other two.